# Text views are not displaying horizontally in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi In the below code text-views are not displaying horizontally .I have 4 `textviews` named as save,off,test,reset displaying horizontally but not in proper order.this is my layout where i did the mistake can any one please help me.

sample.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1c1c1c"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="OFF"
                    android:id="@id/txt_on"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_reset"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RESET"
                    android:id="@id/txt_reset"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_test"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TEST"
                    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_reset"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SAVE"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_on"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use linear layout with horizontal orientation

Comment: use linear layout with horizontal orientation and give your textviews weight.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_50"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```